# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setCrossOrigin' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to run .obj file and .mtl file, but when I run only .obj loader it doesnt show any problem. Running objloader together with mtlloader it gives me an error:

[MTLLoader error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoR0o.png)

Code that I use to load .obj and .mtl files is:

```js
carLoad = new THREE.MTLLoader();
                carLoad.load('assets/obj/audi/Audi_R8.mtl',function(materials){
                materials.preload();
                
                objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials(materials)
                objLoader.load( 'assets/obj/audi/Audi_R8.obj', function ( object ) {
                object.position.set(-50, 0, -60);
                scene.add( object );
});
});
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This runtime error indicates a version mismatch of your library files. You always have to ensure that the core file ( `three.js`) as well as all example files (like `OBJLoader` or `MTLLoader`) are from the same release. Please try it with the latest version which is `r115` right now.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, but again some error. Just to note that i update three.js files and loaders with latest version.
Here is the error:
THREE.Loader: Handlers.get() has been removed. Use LoadingManager.getHandler() instead.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setCrossOrigin' of undefined
    at THREE.MTLLoader.MaterialCreator.loadTexture
    at setMapForType 
    at THREE.MTLLoader.MaterialCreator.createMaterial_
    at THREE.MTLLoader.MaterialCreator.create 
    at THREE.MTLLoader.MaterialCreator.preload 
    at Object.onLoad 
    at XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Can you please share your code as a github repo? It still looks like the files don't match.

Comment: Sorry for late answer... I fix the problem.. Thank you!